# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RepoExists', reason: 'createRepo called for Repo that already exists

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Добрый день!

Убил уже кучу времени, но ничего не помогает, а проблема остаётся. Суть заключается в том что использую Firebase Database Realtime и есть глобальная константа

ref = Database.database().reference()

Первый запуск приложения отрабатывает отлично, но при повторном запуске оно падате с ошибкой:

```
2017-10-24 21:27:39.720991+0300 app[3027:89941] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40004000 started 
2017-10-24 21:27:39.721153+0300 app[3027:89941] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see "GOOGLE URL") 
2017-10-24 21:27:39.824589+0300 app[3027:89762] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RepoExists', reason: 'createRepo called for Repo that already exists.' 
*** First throw call stack: 
( 
0 CoreFoundation 0x00000001125be1cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171 
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000111adaf41 objc_exception_throw + 48 
2 CoreFoundation 0x0000000112632b95 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197 
3 app 0x000000010eabaedf +[FRepoManager createRepo:config:database:] + 357 
4 app 0x000000010eaa2531 -[FIRDatabase ensureRepo] + 151 
5 app 0x000000010eaa1c29 -[FIRDatabase reference] + 31 
6 app 0x000000010ea1bcf8 globalinit_33_CBBC6E383F6D8CD5592C2850E08E2698_func5 + 88 
7 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000115f5f43c _dispatch_client_callout + 8 
8 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000115f609c7 dispatch_once_f + 297 
9 app 0x000000010ea1bd44 _T015app3refSo17DatabaseReferenceCfau + 36 
10 app 0x000000010e9750f8 _T015app18LoadViewControllerC9updateTopyyF + 24 
11 app 0x000000010e970fb5 _T015app18LoadViewControllerC07viewDidC0yyF + 5061 
12 app 0x000000010e971384 _T015app18LoadViewControllerC07viewDidC0yyFTo + 36 
13 UIKit 0x000000011339854d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1235 
14 UIKit 0x000000011339899a -[UIViewController view] + 27 
15 UIKit 0x0000000113266ae3 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 122 
16 UIKit 0x00000001132671eb -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 294 
17 UIKit 0x000000011327a098 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42 
18 UIKit 0x00000001131ec521 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4711 
19 UIKit 0x00000001131f1751 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1720 
20 UIKit 0x00000001135b6e00 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 924 
21 UIKit 0x0000000113989840 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153 
22 UIKit 0x00000001135b69f9 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 249 
23 UIKit 0x00000001135b7257 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 668 
24 UIKit 0x0000000113f2add9 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 262 
25 UIKit 0x0000000113f2ac92 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 444 
26 UIKit 0x0000000113c0c87e __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 420 
27 UIKit 0x0000000113e09e8e _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100 
28 UIKit 0x0000000113c0c67a -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 231 
29 UIKit 0x0000000113988e9d -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392 
30 UIKit 0x00000001131effd2 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 523 
31 UIKit 0x00000001137c489b -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 369 
32 FrontBoardServices 0x000000011b4821b4 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 338 
33 FrontBoardServices 0x000000011b48aca9 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 235 
34 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000115f5f43c _dispatch_client_callout + 8 
35 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000115f64af4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 592 
36 FrontBoardServices 0x000000011b4b66ce __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24 
37 FrontBoardServices 0x000000011b4b6384 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 464 
38 FrontBoardServices 0x000000011b4b68f3 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45 
39 CoreFoundation 0x00000001125612b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17 
40 CoreFoundation 0x0000000112600d31 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81 
41 CoreFoundation 0x0000000112545c19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185 
42 CoreFoundation 0x00000001125451ff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279 
43 CoreFoundation 0x0000000112544a89 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409 
44 GraphicsServices 0x00000001199f99c6 GSEventRunModal + 62 
45 UIKit 0x00000001131f323c UIApplicationMain + 159 
46 app 0x000000010ea235b7 main + 55 
47 libdyld.dylib 0x0000000115fdbd81 start + 1 
) 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException 
(lldb)
```

Как быть? Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной ситуцией?

Метод который использует эту константу:

```
func updateTop() {
        ref.child("Update").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
            if let update = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                for item in update {
                    if String(describing: item.value!) == "true" {
                        refTop.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                            if let topItem = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                                for (index, item) in topItem.enumerated() {
                                    self.utils.loadHotEvent(topId: String(describing: item.childSnapshot(forPath: "id").value!), itemNum: index + 1)
                                }
                                updateTopGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
                                    ref.child("Update/Top").setValue("false")
                                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "segue"), object: nil)
                                })
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "segue"), object: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

вот такая же проблема [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336400/firebase-crashes-out-of-the-blue-with-repoexists-message), попробуйте поставить ваш код в мейн поток вот так

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
    self.ref = Database.database().reference()
}
```

Вот еще [ссылка](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/Database#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabase(py)callbackQueue) у `Database` есть параметр `callbackQueue` который по умолчанию main

Comment: Странно получается ... Констату в main thread нужно объявлять получает?

Comment: видимо сам вызов Database.database().reference() должен в мейне быть

Comment: Но он и так main. Ладно как доберусь до кода, отпишусь как обстоят дела. Кстати добавил метод который использует эту константу